# Descriptor not being invoked and not getting the desired output

Tags: python

```
class MaxLength:
    def __init__(self, max_length):
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print("get called")
        return self.max_length

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise ValueError("Value must be a string")
        
        if len(value) > self.max_length:
            raise ValueError(f"String length exceeds the maximum length of {self.max_length}")

class LimitedString:
    def __init__(self, value, max_length):
        self._max_length = MaxLength(max_length)
        self.value = value

    @property
    def max_length(self):
        return self._max_length

    @max_length.setter
    def max_length(self, value):
        self.value = MaxLength(self._max_length)

limited_str = LimitedString("Short", 10)

# Access the 'max_length' attribute
print(limited_str.max_length)  #Should give Output: 10
limited_str.value = "Too long string"  #Should Raises a ValueError
```

I am trying create a descriptor `MaxLength` such that when we call class `LimitedString("Short", 10)` with `value="Short"` and `max_length=10` when we try to  assign a value of string larger than the max length it raises a `ValueError`. also, Performing all validation in descriptor class `MaxLength`

I neither get the output value of 10 for `limited_str.max_length` nor does it raises value error for `limited_str.max_length`

Comment: A descriptor does not feel like the right tool in this case, in my opinion. Additionally, per-instance configuration is a bit complicated with descriptors. Also, descriptors only work when they are defined as attributes on the **class**, and **not** on the instance as can be seen in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#simple-example-a-descriptor-that-returns-a-constant). Maybe you can clarify why you need a descriptor

Comment: i am just learning , you are right. I should be validating just with the property decorator and should not be trying to do per instance configuration with a descriptor

Comment: For a learning project you could try to make the following code work:
`class LimitedString: value = MaxLength(10)`